# How do I manipulate this string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this challenge:

```
var tx =  "<p>This is a sample picture. <img src="" alt="Sample picture"> This picture is the best for the advertising...</p> ";
```

How do I format this variable to remove the img tag and have a result:

```
    tx = "<p>This is a sample picture. This picture is the best for the advertising...</p> ";
```

Comment: Did you consider using regex?

Comment: `tx.replace(/.../, '')`, using a RegEx. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using Regular Expression. Try this:

```js
var tx =  "<p>This is a sample picture. <img src='' alt='Sample picture'> This picture is the best for the advertising...</p> ";

const res = tx.replace(/<img[^>]+>/, '');

console.log(res);
```